# getting the global coordinates of a component+flex

Tags: apache-flex

I have a texInput component,which is placed inside containers like following

```
<s:BorderContainer ...>
    <mx:VBox ...>
        <mx:HBox ...>
            <mx:TextInput ...>
        </mx:HBox>
    </mx:VBox>
</s:BorderContainer>
```

Now after initialization i want to get the location of my textInput with respect to Application.

I tried with with localToGlobal(PointofLocalCoridnate), then it is not giving the correct location of textInput..Please suggest me....

Thank you...

Comment: can u add ur code so i can edit and tell u what to do?

Comment: you _should_ add a screenshot so we can better understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `myTextInput.getBounds (stage);`?

See [AS3 Doc for DisplayObject#getBounds()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#getBounds%28%29).